# How to dynamically arrange html elements like a button form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, button

I have a two part question on how I can dynamically arrange html buttons. I want to arrange the buttons without reloading the page, so I have been experimenting with jquery.

First, I have a column of html buttons and I want to be able to click on one and have it go to a specific place in the column. For example, if I clicked on one and I wanted it to go to the very top of the column, then i click on another and button and the most recently clicked button goes to the very top of the column.

I'm thinking I could accomplish this with an array of html buttons, but I am new to javascript and I don't know if it's possible to dynamically arrange html buttons in this manner. Is it possible to dynamically arrange html buttons with a javascript array? Is there a better way to arrange html elements?

Second, I would like to dynamically insert new buttons to the top of the column. I have had some success adding new buttons with jquery's before method. But the before method requires me to provide the current button at the top of the column and this doesn't work if I am dynamically arranging and rearranging the buttons.

I have looked into other "DOM Insertion" methods in jquery's API documentation, but I have not found a method to dynamically insert the buttons at the top of the column without specifically providing the top-most button's id.

Again my array concept comes in handy here. I could insert a new button into the zero index of the array, but I have not seen html elements displayed via javascript arrays in code I have viewed.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding part one.  Do you always want the button to go to the bottom?  I just realized that the way you put it can indicate that it could go in a number of places.  How would you signal where a button would go?

Answer (score 0):

**Concerning Part one:**

On click of the button, append it to the container of buttons.

```
<div>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('div');
});
});
</script>
```

**Concerning Part 2:**
when you're adding a button you can use `prepend`.

```
$('button').click(function(){ $('div').prepend('<button>button</button>'); });
```

Here is a fiddle for both parts

here is a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ORoXIHo/1/edit

Comment: Won't the append method add the new button to the end of the container? Say the new button has a distinct value, and I am trying to change the position of it in the container. How can I move it from the bottom to the top?

Comment: When you are adding to the top you can use the `prependTo` method.  I was covering the case of clicking buttons and moving them to the bottom.  I can continue to expand on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `prepend()` / `prependTo()`? You would only need to hold a reference to the container of your column of buttons, then prepend to that.

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NArjL/)

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to dynamically arrange html buttons with a javascript array? Is there a better way to arrange html elements?**

Lists of elements in javascript are typed as NodeLists. The DOM contains all of the Nodes and NodeLists. As such, they are accessible through `document`. In jQuery you can target these Nodes. jQuery will wrap each Node in an object, and if multiple Nodes are present, it will create an array of these jQuery objects.

**I could insert a new button into the zero index of the array, but I have not seen html elements displayed via javascript arrays in code I have viewed.**

```
var newButton = $("<input type='button' class='btn' />");
var htmlElements = $(".btn");
newButton.insertBefore(htmlElements.first());
```